# Paradox observed while studying Euler's formula

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I am a first-year uni student. While messing around with Euler's formula I got this paradox
$$e^{i\theta}=(e^{i2\pi})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}=(\cos(2\pi) + i \sin(2\pi))^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}=1$$
I asked my university tutor and he didn't know the answer either. How can I explain this?

Comment: I believe you did something when you wrote the bracket around the powers. Read about principle roots, etc.

Comment: what is $\theta$?  has it occured to you that $1^{1\over 2}$ has multiple values.

Comment: Complex power rules are not the same as real power rules.

Comment: $e^{i\theta p} = (e^{i\theta})^p,$ only if p is an integer